# Как разграничить классы CI - уровни доступа?

Tags: php, ооп, codeigniter

Сейчас внимание остановилось на двух написанных пользовательских классах, которые написаны в одном файле php:
Profile и EditProfile.

```
class Profile extends Auth {
}

class EditProfile extends Profile {
}
```

В первом классе, предусмотрены все **необходимые методы** для получения информации об АВТОРИЗИРОВАННОМ, текущем пользователе.

Входной точной класса Profile, является метод:

```
public function index($section = 'personal'){
        $this->route();
    }
```

который принимает параметр, определяющий, какую информацию отобразить для авторизированного пользователя.
К чему все это? К тому, что нужен механизм отображения *frontend* профилей пользователей, защищенный. Так как в классе *Profile* имеются методы *edit*.

Вопрос стоит в архитектуре ООП. Можно написать еще один класс, в котором продублировать все **необходимые методы**, которые уже есть в классе Profile (что не хочется делать), или же добавить еще одну входную точку в класс **Profile** и определять ее другим адресом в route?

Например, запросить профайл пользователя по адресу URL: */profile/user/23*
Тогда в классе **Profile** определить публичный метод **user()**, принимающий целочисленный параметр 23, а внутри него создать экземпляр класса:
    public function user($idUser = null){
        $publicProfile = new PublicProfile($idUser);
    }

Где **PublicProfile** - 3-й класс *extends* класс **Profile**

Таким образом управление профайлами передается польностью классу **PublicProfile**, при этом имея доступ к private методам  класс родителя Profile.

Что Вы думаете по этому поводу? Какие есть предложения у знатоков ООП? В целом задача разграничить уровень доступа к просмотру/редактированию профайла.

Comment: Может к какому-то паттерну присмотреться?

Comment: > классах, которые написаны в одном файле

первый тревожный звонок

> необходимые методы для получения информации ... о ... пользователе.
>
> Входной точной класса ... является метод ... index

У вас класс - это все-таки контроллер или репозиторий данных о пользователе?

> Можно написать еще один класс, в котором продублировать все необходимые методы

Я слегка потерял нить, но общий ответ будет **нет, никогда и ни за что не дублировать написанный код**

Comment: > Таким образом управление профайлами передается польностью классу PublicProfile, при этом имея доступ к private методам класс родителя Profile.

Во-первых, к приватным методам у него доступа не будет.

Во-вторых, если вы пытаетесь реализовать фильтр неавторизованных пользователей через публичность метода на уровне PHP, то это затея, изначально обреченная на провал.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Как бы вы организовали такую структуру классов для этой задачи? Может будет навыком мне

Comment: Класс - больше как репозиторий данных - потому что большая часть методов для выборки данных о пользователях

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk сначала я бы просто написал задачу в виде ТЗ, потому что я ее так и не понял. Потом я бы разделил логику и отделил контроллеры от моделей. Ну и в третью очередь я пошел бы смотреть доки CI, чтобы узнать, как делается фильтрация по авторизации.

Comment: Все что вы написали - это есть. Все разделено по архитектуре MVC.
Задача стоит такая, написать классы профилей пользователей. Классы должны предоставлять всю информацию о пользователе (страница пользователя), а для авторизированного пользователя еще и возможность управлять профилей(редактировать).

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk

> Все разделено по архитектуре MVC.

> Класс - больше как репозиторий данных - потому что большая часть методов для выборки данных о пользователях

ну да, ну да